# Copying data from another cell (if statement, maybe?)

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have two tabs of data and I want to be able to copy the data into one of the tabs if a certain criteria is met.

I know a `VLOOKUP` would suffice usually, however, one part of the data is going into a column within a pivot table.

Sheet 1 would contain:

```
Account Comment
1000    
1000    
1000    
1000    
1000    
1000    
1000    
3000    
3000    
3000    
3000    
3000    
3000    
5000    
5000    
5000    
5000    
5000    
7500    
7500    
7500    
7500    
7500    
7500    
7500
```

Sheet 2 contains:

```
Account Comment
1000    Test
3000    Test 1
5000    Test 2
7500    Test 3
```

I would like to be able to show the the comments on sheet 2 in sheet 1.

So against 1000 in sheet one it would say 'Test', 3000 would say 'Test 1'
etc.

Comment: *one part of the data is going into a column within a pivot table* Which part? Where is the Pivot Table? Are the data in both seets to be always in the same columns?

Answer (score 1):

Yes a compound IF statement will do this.

It really depends on how many different numbers you are going to be using as it will become very cumbersome with say 20+ numbers.

In the above example:

```
=IF(A2=1000,"Test",IF(A2=3000,"Test 1",IF(A2=5000,"Test 2",IF(A2=7500,"Test 3"),"")))
```

etc, continue as needed and copy down.